# How do i get this in asynctask

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, background, android-asynctask

i got my app working so it returns the information from a json api.
now i realize that i have to put everything in a asynch task so it doesn't crash as much 
and a progress dialog is easier, only i really don't know how to do this so im wondering if somebody knows a really good tutorial or wants to edit my code a bit to get my started

```
    package net.thinkbin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class culture extends ListActivity {

private static final String TITLE = "Title";
private static final String AUTHOR = "Author";
private static final String VIEWS = "Views";
private static final String RATES = "Rates";
private static final String CONTENT = "Content";
final Context context = this;

JSONArray ideas = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder2);

    Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.TUTORIAL1"));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.SHARE"));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonhome);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);

            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Loading...");
            ImageView image = (ImageView)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hourglass);

            dialog.show();
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    startActivity(new  Intent("net.thinkbin.MENU"));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();

                }
            });
            th.start();
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.spinnerorder,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
     adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cultureorder);
    s.setAdapter(adapter2);

    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter2, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 1) {
                startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.CULTURE2"));
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.CULTURE3"));
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                finish();
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,  String>>();

    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
             .getJSONfromURL("http://www.thinkbin.net/include/api/index.php? cat=Culture&type=Newest&i=10");

    try {

        ideas = json.getJSONArray("Ideas");

        for (int i = 0; i < ideas.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = ideas.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = c.getString(TITLE);
            String author = c.getString(AUTHOR);
            String views = c.getString(VIEWS);
            String rates = c.getString(RATES);
            String content = c.getString(CONTENT);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String> ();

            map.put(TITLE, "Title: " + title);
            map.put(AUTHOR, "Author: " + author);
            map.put(VIEWS, "Views: " + views);
            map.put(RATES, "Rates: " + rates);
            map.put(CONTENT, content);

            mylist.add(map);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.main2,
            new String[] { TITLE, AUTHOR, VIEWS, RATES, CONTENT },
            new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle,  R.id.item3,
                    R.id.item4, R.id.item5 });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String Title2 = ((TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.item_title))
                    .getText().toString();
            String Author2 = ((TextView) view
                     .findViewById(R.id.item_subtitle)).getText().toString();
            String Content2 = ((TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.item5))
                    .getText().toString();

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  idea.class);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            in.putExtra(TITLE, Title2);
            in.putExtra(AUTHOR, Author2);
            in.putExtra(CONTENT, Content2);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is good class **AsyncTask** to do something Asyncronius in Android.

Example:

> private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask
>   {
>
> ```
>  protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
>      int count = urls.length;
>      long totalSize = 0;
>      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
>          totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
>          publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
>      }
>      return totalSize;
>  }
>
>  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
>      setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
>  }
>
>  protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
>      showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
>  }  }
> ```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: thanks, but do you know a good tutorial or can you edit my code a bit to get me started